# Python import failure for one directory only

Tags: python, import

I have a directory structure of libraries and tests as generalized below. I have __init__.py files in all lib and test directories however all tests in testcases/Ethernet come up with the error "*E   ImportError: No module named lib*" were all tests in the other directories work fine. The first import in all tests is exactly the same "*from lib import Selftest*" but in all the tests in the testcase/Ethernet directory dir this is the problem line.

I'd like to know how one directory could have this problem when all the others don't, yet they are all set up exactly the same.

Cheers

Si

```
lib/
lib/plugins
lib/boards
lib/ethernet
testcases/Plugins
testcases/Boards
testcases/Ethernet
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that you aren't importing `lib` properly as your test is being run from the `testcases` directory. Have you tried doing a `sys.path.append('../')`, or changing the working directory (though this second option may break the tests)?

Comment: I was running all the tests from the parent dir that contains lib and testcases. It wouldn't explain why only one directory would have the issue. I did trace the issue in the end to a '-' in the path name for a sub directory, and I've answered the question for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally traced the issue to another sub directory under the testcases/Ethernet directory that had a '-' in the name. PWR-AUX_Plugin.

Renaming the directory to PWR_AUX_Plugin fixed the issue.